# ReferenceError when using MongoDB Collection variable in external resolver file that was imported via mergeResolvers

Tags: javascript, mongodb, express, graphql, graphql-js

This is a totally reduced example to better explain the issue! So when I use the **resolver Query** `getAllUsers`, the **MongoDB Collection** `Users` is not available in the external resolver file `user.js`. So when I send that query I get:

> ReferenceError: Users is not defined

That's a correct behaviour. But I do not want to include all the resolvers in my index.js, because I have a better modularization in this way. So I have all my typedefs and resolvers in external files like this.

### Current file structure

```
index.js 
  /graphql
    /typdef
      user.graphql
    /resolver
      user.js
```

The `user.graphql` schema is correctly working. It is just the `user.js` that is producing the error when I execute the query with the not available `Users` variable, as already said.

Here the `index.js` and `user.js`.

### index.js

```
import express from 'express'
import cors from 'cors'
const app = express()
app.use(cors())
import bodyParser from 'body-parser'
import {graphqlExpress, graphiqlExpress} from 'graphql-server-express'
import {makeExecutableSchema} from 'graphql-tools'
import {fileLoader, mergeTypes, mergeResolvers} from 'merge-graphql-schemas';
import {writeFileSync} from 'fs'
const typeDefs = mergeTypes(fileLoader(`${__dirname}/graphql/typedef/*.graphql`), { all: true })
writeFileSync(`${__dirname}/graphql/typedef.graphql`, typeDefs)

export const start = async () => {
  try {
    const MONGO_URL = 'mongodb://localhost:27017'
    const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
    MongoClient.connect(MONGO_URL, function(err, client) {
      console.log("Connected successfully to server");
      const db = client.db('project');
      const Users = db.collection('user')
    });
    const URL = 'http://localhost'
    const homePath = '/graphql'
    const PORT = 3001
    app.use(
      homePath, 
      bodyParser.json(), 
      graphqlExpress({schema})
      )
    app.use(homePath, 
      graphiqlExpress({
        endpointURL: homePath
      })
    )
    app.listen(PORT, () => {
      console.log(`Visit ${URL}:${PORT}${homePath}`)
    })
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e)
  }
}
```

### user.js

```
export default {
  Query: {
    getAllUsers: async () => {
    return (await Users.find({}).toArray()).map(prepare)
    }
  }
}
```

What is the best way to pass the MongoDB or the `Users` collection to the resolver files. Or is there an even better solution for this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, this is NOT a proper solution, because declaring global variables while outsourcing schema is a bad design at all. But it works out and maybe this way someone gets an idea about how to improve this fix.

So to solve the issue all I had to do is changing the variable from local **const to global**.

So in **index.js** `const Users = db.collection('user')` is rewritten by `global.Users = db.collection('user')`.

Same for the **user.js**. Here `return (await Users.find({}).toArray()).map(prepare)` is rewritten by `return (await global.Users.find({}).toArray()).map(prepare)`.